# ODE with a measurable vector field

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

Suppose we have a bounded Borel measurable vector field $F:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$. To make the question non-trivial, assume that $F\neq 0$ eveywhere.

> **Question.** Does there exist at least one Lipschitz integral curve? That is a Lipschitz function $\varphi:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}^n$ such that
>   $\varphi'(t)=F(\varphi(t))$ for almost all $t\in (a,b)$.

This question is related to:
[Set of integral curves of a vector field](https://mathoverflow.net/q/255525/121665).

Comment: If $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is a measurable set such that $|(a, b) \cap A| > 0$ and $|(a, b) \setminus A| > 0$ whenever $a < b$, and $F(x) = -1 + 2 \times \mathbb{1}_A(x)$, then, if I am not mistaken, there is no solution $\varphi$.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki I think this example can be easily generalized to higher dimensions by taking $F$ on each component with "separated variables". Please change your comment into an answer including higher dimensions. This is very nice.

Comment: The example mentioned by @MateuszKwaśnicki is also mentioned in the paper "A Necessary and Sufficient Condition for Existence of Measurable Flow of a Bounded Borel Vector Field" by Nikolay A. Gusev, Moscow Mathematical Journal 18(1):85-92, 2018.

Comment: @Skeeve Thank for the reference! I will certainly read it.

Comment: @Skeeve: If you like, feel free to write a more detailed answer based on Gusev's article, I'll be happy to read it. And I am too busy at the moment to turn my comment into an answer, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For completeness let me add some details (as suggested by @MateuszKwaśnicki).

Let $A\subseteq \mathbb R$ be [a Borel set of positive but not full measure in each interval](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57317/construction-of-a-borel-set-with-positive-but-not-full-measure-in-each-interval), set $F(x) = -1 + 2 \cdot 1_{A}(x)$. Let $\varphi\colon (a,b) \to \mathbb R$ be a Lipschitz integral curve of $F$.

The set $R = \varphi((a,b))$ is an interval (by the intermediate value property) with positive Lebesgue measure (because $\varphi'(t)\ne 0$ for a.e. $t\in(a,b)$). Consider the set
$$
\tilde R = \{x \in R : \forall t \in \varphi^{-1}(\{x\}) \; \exists \varphi'(t) = F(\varphi(t)) \}
$$
The set $R\setminus \tilde R$ is Lebesgue negligible, being the image of a Lebesgue negligible set $\{t \in (a,b) : \not\exists \varphi'(t) \text{ or } \varphi'(t) \ne F(\varphi(t))\}$ under Lipschitz map $\varphi$.

Note that for any $x\in \tilde R$ there exists just one $t\in (a,b)$ such that $\varphi(t)=x$. Indeed, otherwise one could find distinct points $t_1, t_2 \in (a,b)$ such that $\varphi(t_1) = \varphi(t_2) = x \in \tilde R$ and $\varphi(t) - x$ has constant sign on $(t_1, t_2)$. Then $\varphi'(t_1)$ and $\varphi'(t_2)$ have to have different signs, a contradiction with the definition of $\tilde R$. Therefore $\varphi$ is injective on $\varphi^{-1}(\tilde R)$. Then it is easy to show that $\varphi$ is injective on the whole $(a,b)$, using the fact that $\varphi'(t)\ne 0$ for a.e. $t\in(a,b)$.

By continuity and injectivity the function $\varphi$ is strictly monotone, hence one of the sets $R \cap A$ and $R \setminus A$ has measure zero (because $\varphi$ cannot map a negligible set to a set with positive measure). This contradicts the definition of $A$.

In higher dimensions one could take $F(x) = (-1 + 2 \cdot 1_{A}(x_1), 1, \ldots, 1)$.

Comment: In higher dimensions you need to modify your construction. The set $A$ is one dimensional so $1_A(x)$ makes no sense. Did you mean $1_A(x_1)$?

Comment: @PiotrHajlasz fixed, thanks!